# FB Login : Don't know how to get response after a successful login

Tags: facebook

I have added an fblogin button to my website
it is working fine 
a button is placed and when user clicks on it a dialogue box opens for login.

But i don't know how to get response after a successful login.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JS SDK to subscribe to events of that type. Take a look at the [facebook javascript documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), the method you are looking for is `'auth.authResponseChange'`  :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```